# Youtube API - relevance_lang_languageCode vs lr parameter

Tags: youtube-api

i think that the relevance_lang_languageCode doesn't work or i didn't understand How... ...with language restriction it finds only video for a specific language (and i agree) but with orderby=relevance_lang_languageCode it doesn't insert (at least) for first the videos from that specific language...
example:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?vq=MSI%20GTX%20680%20Twin&orderby=relevance_lang_de
```

it seems to work...but

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?vq=MSI%20GTX%20680%20Twin&orderby=relevance_lang_it
```

even if

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?vq=MSI%20GTX%20680%20Twin&lr=it
```

finds video from italian language...
do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve videos that are in Italian, use `lr=it`. You can use that in conjunction with `orderby=relevance_lang_it` if you want to retrieve results that are ordered by relevance to Italian speakers and are all in Italian. It's not an either/or thing with those two parameters.

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=MSI%20GTX%20680%20Twin&orderby=relevance_lang_it&v=2&lr=it

The documentation for `orderby=` explains that even when you specify `relevance_lang_LC`, the results are not guaranteed to be in that language.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#orderbysp

Comment: i think that i can't do exactly what i want, 'cause if i put lr=it i can't retrieve other languages... instead it would be useful if a parameter allows to retrieve the first videos it finds for a language...and then possibly the others ;-)

Comment: that is...i can't do it easily, i would need to code something...would be better to avoid

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not possible. This isn't just a question of tweaking a API parameter; the video data isn't ordered in the manner you're looking for.